# using pdb file in 3Dmol.js

Tags: data-modeling, pdb

I'm trying to modelize proteins using the 3Dmol.js library.

here my code usues the pdb id of the protein u can test it and it works.. but i want to use local pdb file on my computer..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="http://3Dmol.csb.pitt.edu/build/3Dmol-min.js">
</script>

<div id="element1" style="height: 1000px; width: 1000px; position: relative;" class='viewer_3Dmoljs' data-pdb1= '2hmi' data-backgroundcolor='0xffffff' data-style='cartoon:color=#ABC8E2' data-surface= 'opacity:1;color:white' data-select1='chain:A' data-surface1='opacity:3;color:green'>
</div>
```

I tried **data-href='fileLocation/fileName.pdb'**

error message: 3Dmol-min.js:176 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://fileLocation/fileName.pdb. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: Put the `pdb` file into the folder where your `html` is, and use relative path

Comment: they're already in the same folder

Comment: then may download `3Dmol-min.js` to this folder too

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found out:

Javascript is not allowed to arbitrarily access files on a local computer.  If it were, any website would be able to steal all your data.  the solution is to provide a URL to a file being served by a webserver.

Quick fix: I installed this small server [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en) app in chrome. Opened the app and pointed the file location (URL) in my code.
And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I tried the method mentioned in the answer by @ana akana but it did not work. Instead, saving the file to `/static` folder works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="http://3Dmol.csb.pitt.edu/build/3Dmol-min.js"></script>

<div id="element1" style="height: 1000px; width: 1000px; position: relative;" class='viewer_3Dmoljs' data-href='/static/fileName.pdb' data-backgroundcolor='0xffffff' data-style='cartoon:color=#ABC8E2' data-surface= 'opacity:1;color:white' data-select1='chain:A' data-surface1='opacity:3;color:green'>
</div>
```